# Two targets of mine do not see Objective-c Generated Interface Header Name

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have four targets in my projects: two of them correctly found their  Objective-c Generated Interface Header Name and two do not. I doublechecked the names of the files corresponded to the ones in the directives: this is how I derive the four files:

```
#ifdef hd
#import "inArrivoHD-Swift.h"
#elif express
#import "inArrivo_Express-Swift.h"
#elif taxi_coops
#import "Limo_Manager-Swift.h"
#elif share
#import "Share&Spare-Swift.h"
#endif
```

The former two are found and the latter two are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is always the same issue of some irregularity in some other parts of the project on the basis of which Xcode decides not to create the Swift.h file.